# Getting only 30 frames from videos with varying number of frames using VideoCapture in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, mediapipe

I am trying to extract keypoints using mediapipe to train an LSTM model to detect sign language actions(only for a set of adjectives for now). The training dataset is being parsed and passed to VideoCapture, which is then used to extract keypoints through mediapipe's holistic model, which are then saved as numpy arrays for each frame in .npy files in respective directories. However, due to varying video lengths, the total number of frames captured and thus the number of numpy arrays generated are varying for each video, which is not suitable for the training architecture. It would be straightforward to simply break out of the loop when 30 frames have been captured, but that would exract data only for first 30 frames, which is not desirable. Is there a way to not skip over data whilst getting only a fixed number of frames per video.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time
import mediapipe as mp


DATASET_PATH = "/home/kuna71/Dev/HearMySign/Datasets/Adjectives_1of8/Adjectives"
KEYPOINT_PATH = "/home/kuna71/Dev/HearMySign/Keypoints"
sequence_len = 30

mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

def mediapipe_detection(image, model):
    print("In mediapipe_detection function")
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # COLOR CONVERSION BGR 2 RGB
    image.flags.writeable = False                  # Image is no longer writeable (just to save on some memory)
    results = model.process(image)                 # Make prediction
    image.flags.writeable = True                   # Image is now writeable
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) # COLOR COVERSION RGB 2 BGR
    return image, results

def extract_keypoints(results):
    pose = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z, res.visibility] for res in results.pose_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.pose_landmarks else np.zeros(33*4)
    face = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.face_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.face_landmarks else np.zeros(468*3)
    lh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.left_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(21*3)
    rh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.right_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(21*3)
    return np.concatenate([pose, face, lh, rh])

#opencv code to capture frames
directories = os.listdir(DATASET_PATH)

for d in directories:
    vids = os.listdir(os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, d))
    for v in vids:
        videopath = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, d, v)
        print("\n\n\n\n\n__________________CHANGING VIDEO__________________\n\n\n\n\n")
        print("\n\n________VIDEOPATH:"+videopath)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videopath)
        
        length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        print("LENGTH:" + str(length))
        # Set mediapipe model
        with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
            count =0
            while cap.isOpened():
                count=count+1
                print("Reading feed")          
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if(frame is None):
                    break
                image, result = mediapipe_detection(frame, holistic)
             

                result_test = extract_keypoints(result)
                print(result_test)
                if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(KEYPOINT_PATH, d, v)):
                    os.makedirs(os.path.join(KEYPOINT_PATH, d, v))
                NPY_PATH = os.path.join(KEYPOINT_PATH, d, v, str(count))
                np.save(NPY_PATH, result_test)

                # Show to screen
                cv2.imshow('OpenCV Feed', image)

                # Break gracefully
                if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can you better explain what kind of output you want, if a video has more than 30 frames? If I understand you correctly, in then end you want 30 frames, but not the first 30 frames. What else do you want? 30 equally distributed frames out of N>30 frames? With videocapture.get you can read the total number of frames in a video and from that values you can calculate how many frames you want to skip between processed frames.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Micka That is what I'm looking for. My first judgement was to randomly skip frames to get only 30 frames. However, I wished to know if there was a faster inbuilt solution to this.  The output I wish to obtain is 30 frames for each video without skipping over significant parts of the video.